# How should I implement a runonce script for Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, command-line-interface

I use Scrum methodology and deploy functionality in builds every sprint.

There is necessity to perform different changes in the stored data (I mean data in database and on filesystem). I'd like to implement it as a PHP scripts invoked from console. But they should be executed only once, during the deployment.

Is there any way to implement it through `app/console` without listing it in the list of registered Console commands? Or is there any other way to implement runonce scripts?

DoctrineMigrations covers some part of my requirements, but it's hard to implement complex changes in Model. And it does not cover changes in files on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think symfony has a facility for that, and besides, hiding the command is not the same as securing the command.

Instead, I would make the script determine if it has been run already (could be as simple as adding a version number to a file and checking that number before running) and stop if it detects it has already run before.

Comment: But I want to hide these entries from the list of commands because there could be a lot of such runonce scripts. And the output will be too verbose in this case.